# read a specific area in excel using R

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am using R and I need to read data form specific area in my excel file. For example read data in this area : C8:I21

How can we do that using R ? there is a specific package for it ?

some help would be appreciated

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/read-excel-files-from-r/ ?

Comment: `library(xlsx); ?readRange`

Comment: You couldn't find any existing information online about how to use `R` to do the most basic task you can do with an Excel worksheet?

Comment: Another possible packages is "Readxl"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of packages that will read Excel files. 
I favour openxlsx as it doesn't have any Java dependencies.

You can set the rows and columns you want to read with `rows` and `cols`. 
For example, if I wanted to read ten rows, from row 18 and 5 columns from column 7:

```
library(openxlsx)

my_dat <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "./latest_data/NHS_England_downloads/Beds-Open-Overnight-Web_File-Final-Q1-2015-16-52341.xlsx", 
                    sheet = 1, rows = c(18:27), cols = c(7:11), 
                    colNames = FALSE)
head(my_dat)
        X1       X2 X3      X4 X5
1 748.5055 692.5055  0 56.0000  0
2 759.5824 727.5824  0 32.0000  0
3 692.8022 655.8022  0 37.0000  0
4 153.1758 153.1758  0  0.0000  0
5 205.7582 198.7582  0  0.0000  7
6 553.0110 525.7143  0 27.2967  0
```

Comment: I am trying to read from an already open xlsm, I get this error:
``Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument.
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : error 1 in extracting from zip file.``

Comment: Extract the file from the zip and save it in a normal folder, maybe?